# Word for emotionally not affected by anything

Tags: word-request

Something happy or sad or exciting happens to the person and they are emotionally unmoved. They may form strong cognitive and/or physical response but are emotionally 'meh'.

This would be exhibited by someone who is considered mentally healthy but their personality is to ignore emotions in many circumstance.

Additionally, the word has to have no positive or negative connotation.

Examples:

He found his car burning; but he was X and proceeded to examine the situation.

A surprise birthday party! He smiled and hugged his friends but was actually X.

The code was broken for third week straight. Anyone would have gone crazy but she was X.

Comment: Are you looking for somebody who is pathologically unemotional? Or are you looking for somebody who is seriously disciplined so has emotion but does not show it?

Comment: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/showing-no-emotions-and-unaffected-by-emotions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *imperturbable* or one of its synonyms.

> unable to be upset or excited; calm. ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20imperturbable&forcedict=imperturbable&dictcorpus=en&expnd=1))

You can find plenty of synonyms on [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/imperturbable.html).

Have a look at what [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impassive) says about ***impassive***:

> IMPASSIVE, STOIC, PHLEGMATIC, APATHETIC, STOLID mean unresponsive to something that might normally excite interest or emotion.

Comment: 'unperturbed' is exactly what I had in mind. Now comes the hard part for me: finding a translation in my native language.

Comment: Well, in Russian it is невозмутимый, if this helps...

Comment: [BG] равнодушен [/BG]. Hooray! (I've been using a word literally translated to APATHETIC and not knowing it has entirely negative connotation)

Comment: Oh, definitely good find! Much better than mine!